# Flash AS3, Is it possible to change anti-alias setting of static text through code?

Tags: actionscript-3, antialiasing, embedded-fonts

I'm working with swf's generated by InDesign CS5, which will apparently only export text as staticText objects. Is it possible to alter the anti-alias of staticText? I want to make it for readability, but it defaults to animation with no apparent way of changing it. I recently got help for textFields, but I can't seem to get it to work on staticText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

static text cannot be read or changed at run time.  It's really not even text.  It's shapes written out by the Flash IDE that happen to represent text to the viewer, but as far as Flash is concerned, it's just more shapes.

To read/edit/modify/whatever text at run time you need to use a text field.  I'm not sure if there's any way to get InDesign to output swfs with text fields instead of static text.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to change aliassing. It is only possible to detect a static textfield and get its text trough code.

```
for (var i:int= 0;i < this.numChildren; i++)
{
 if (getChildAt(i) is StaticText)
 {
   trace("Found a StaticText in ", this , "with text:", StaticText(getChildAt(i)).text)
 }
}
```